# Get the list of String from a HTTP response in JAVA

Tags: java, http

My HTTP GET call response looks like this

```
   ["String1", "String2","String3"]
```

As it is not a JSON response I need to get all the values within the array of that response and add them to a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually it is a valid JSON - https://jsonlint.com/.

You can parse the JSON using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
List<String> strs = jsonArray.toList().stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(strs);
```

Output:

```
[String1, String2, String3]
```

---

Or under the assumption that the input is formatted like this and each string does not contain quotes, you can do:

```
String substring = json.substring(1, json.length() - 1);
List<String> strs = Arrays.stream(substring.split(","))
        .map(s -> s.replace("\"", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(strs);
```

Output:

```
[String1,  String2, String3]
```